# iPhone app - Support Portrait Orientation Only With Storyboard

Tags: iphone, rotation, storyboard, orientation, portrait

new to iPhone and having difficulty with making an iPhone app *only* support portrait.

I'm using storyboarding and targeting iOS5+.

I've had a good look on here, and the suggestions for other people haven't worked for me.

I've tried implementing

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation       
 {
      return NO;
 }
```

on view controllers, and changing my info.plist to

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

but no joy. 
In the storyboard I've also chosen portrait in the attributes editor.

Any more ideas?

Many thanks,
    Jordan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the orientation buttons that show up when selecting your target on xCode4?

[image]

Comment: siiiiiiiiigh.  
In the supported device orientations, Portrait was the only one selected. I deselected it, and clicked it again.
Now it works! Have found so many bugs in xcode today..
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use below options for the same method. No need to change in plist file.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
}
```

here I use **UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait** and **UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown** with or condition, using this I allow application rotate only in portrait mode.

If you want your application can rotate in all view sides then **return YES** in above method.**return NO** indicate you want view don't rotate anyway.